# multiple custom cursor css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor

I have problem with custom cursor which works for me when I just just one command "cursor" on one element.

**EXAMPLE** [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bCmxy?editors=110)

**Explanation what I'm looking for:**

-On **GREY** half everything is working fine, `hover` element has other "pointer" and "default" cursor is some other "arrow". But it works only when I create `class="pointer"` for element with text "hover"

-On **CYAN** half command

```
cursor: url("http://revelier.home.pl/SZYMON/images/cursor/link.cur"), pointer;
```

is working it replace pointer cursor for my custom, but does not read my default/custom cursor

**What I want to accomplish:**

-have ability to change cursor doesn't matter if it will be css or jquery, for example "pointer" for other custom cursor, "wait" for something, "crosshair" for my custom "x" cursor etc etc...

All I can do for now is change one cursor on each element, which is unacceptable.
I'd like to apply for all styles

```
body{ 
  cursor: url("x"),pointer;
  cursor: url("y"), crosshair; 
  cursor: url("q"), wait;  
}
```

Comment: Ups... didn't notice your demo

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor). The second option in `pointer` is NOT the "pointer you want to replace", it is the fallback system pointer to use if the file isn't available.

Comment: ok, well that's awkward, my bad - sorry then for my lack of information. But anyway do you have any idea to change cursor for all for example :hover elements?